# PHP DateTime difference in hours with timezone gives 0 instead of 2

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

I'm trying to build a list of timezone with the time difference between the php timezone code and UTC.

I've try a few lines of code with diff:

```
$utc_date = new DateTime(
    NULL,
    new DateTimeZone('UTC')
);
echo 'UTC:  ' . $utc_date->format('Y-m-d g:i A') . "<br>";

$cairo_date = new DateTime(
    NULL,
    new DateTimeZone('Africa/Cairo')
);
echo 'Cairo:  ' . $cairo_date->format('Y-m-d g:i A') . "<br>";

$diff = $utc_date->diff($cairo_date);
echo "Differences: " . $diff->h;
```

It outputs that:

```
UTC: 2020-05-17 9:14 PM
Cairo: 2020-05-17 11:14 PM
Differences: 0
```

I can't find why diff doesn't return the correct differences ?

Comment: They're the same moment in time, just different timezones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diff function you call will return different timestamp. So, there are same moment will return 0. You should call different time zone between them. Exmaple:

```
$utc_date = new DateTime(
    NULL,
    new DateTimeZone('UTC')
);
echo 'UTC:  ' . $utc_date->format('Y-m-d g:i A') . "<br>";

$cairo_date = new DateTime(
    NULL,
    new DateTimeZone('Africa/Cairo')
);
echo 'Cairo:  ' . $cairo_date->format('Y-m-d g:i A') . "<br>";

$cairo_timeZone = timezone_open('Africa/Cairo');

echo "Differences: " . timezone_offset_get($cairo_timeZone, $utc_date)/3600; //hour
```

Answer (score 0):

It's already the same time only in different time zones. Your first param in the DateTime-constructor is null, it means current time.

Try:

```
//add
$utc_date->modify('+1 hour');
```

new output would be:

```
UTC:  2020-05-17 11:01 PM
Cairo:  2020-05-18 12:01 AM
Differences: 1
```

Comment: Thanks, of course, it's the same time, haven't thought about that.